# Text truncation based on cell width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need `javascript` solution for `ellipsis` text truncation.

There is a percentage table which can be re-sized according to the screen resolution. While re-sizing the screen, when the table cell reached `20px` it should truncate the text inside it. Which means it should not decrease the width below `20px`.

I have done this using css solution (`ellipsis`) but unfortunately it is not widely supported for all browsers So I am looking for pure java-script solution to truncate the text by calculating the cell width.

here is how I am using css for this

```
td{
  background:#cccc33;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rehewedolese/2/)**

Comment: What browser do you need to support that *doesn't* support `text-overflow`? I believe it's supported as far back as IE6, although you'll need to add the `-o-text-overflow` version if you need to support Opera 9 or 10.